# Is there a 'better' way to find a list of files in a directory tree

Tags: bash, replace

I have created a list of files using `find`, `foundlist.lst`.

The find command is simply `find . -type f -name "<search_pattern>" > foundlist.lst`

I would now like to use this list to find copies of these files in other directories.

The 'twist' in my requirements is that I want to search only for the 'base' of the file name. I don't want to include the extension in the search.

Example:

`./sort.cc` is a member of the list. I want to look for all files of the pattern `sort.*`

Here is what I wrote. It works. It seems to me that there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
./findfiles.sh foundfiles.lst /usr/bin/temp

#!/bin/bash
# findfiles.sh
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Need two arguments"
    echo "usage: findfiles <filelist> <dir_to_search>"
else
    filename=$1
    echo "$filename"
    while read -r line; do
        name=$line
        # change './file.ext' to 'file.*'
        search_base=$( echo ${name} | sed "s%\.\/%%" | sed "s/\..*/\.\*/" )
        find $2 -type f -name $search_base
    done < $filename
fi
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is the best place for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stripping the file, I'd use the following (instead of awk)

```
search_base=`basename ${name} | cut -d'.' -f1`
```